# Get ELB IP Address in NGINX

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

My Nginx is behind a Classic ELB, and it already works. For restriction reason, I want to get the ELB IP Address. So, if there is upcoming request from 1 ELB i will allow that and if the incoming email from the other ELB there is will be another Logic to prevent/restrict it.  But for now, i just want to make nginx know where LB that forward the request. How can I achieve getting ELB ip address in NGINX?

Comment: be warned the ELB IP can change at anytime

Comment: yes, but if I make a certain subnet just for ELB, i will get the ip range that can indicate that its from specific ELB.